Estate beneficiary required to sign affidavit to agree to accounting which has omissions as requirement for early dispersement?
Is an Affidavit waiving rights for access to accounting with unresolved questions/omissions a requirement to receive an early dispersement? Background:  As a beneficiary, in reviewing the (16 month) 1st estate accounting, several omissions were noted, such as tractor/property equipment and accounting of $400k house proceeds for 3 months prior to deposit. I requested clarifications and an early dispersement (based on 500k in a checking account earning $ 0 interest- fiduciary management?).  The executor sent an Affidavit requiring I agree with the 1st accounting in entirety and waive access rights to accounting related to that time frame, before an early dispersement will be made.  I will sign a refunding bond.  The executor and the other family beneficiaries are all local/neighbors, who possess estate tangible property without accounting, while my side family beneficiaries are out of State and seldom receive status updates unless we specifically request.

early disbursement is not a requirement for estates.  Sign or don't.

The executor has decided that it is, so it is
The executor has both responsibility and liability for the management of the estate in the best interest of the beneficiaries.
You have asked for an early disbursement, which is within the discretion of the executor. You have also raised issues with the estate’s accounts, which would give a prudent executor pause. They have decided that the best interests of the beneficiaries are best served by allowing an early disbursement only if they are protected from the accounting errors. Seems a sensible course of action to me.
